# The Greatest Test Drive Ever!

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

So I went by a car dealership yesterday evening with the intent to buy a used car; upon test driving it, I fell in love with it! This thing was the perfect combination of luxury and sport, and the fact that it was a manual made it all the better. I only have one problem; the price tag. Now, I can put up a sizeable down payment on this thing and drive away with payments in the $600 USD range for the next four years, or I can just walk away. I've decided to make a riddle about the car, and after you guess what it is (if you did any research), do you think I should give it more consideration or just walk away?

> British designed, like driving in heaven;
>
> A famous car worldwide, driven by seven.
>
> My heart is pounding, right out of my chest;
>
> Dumping the clutch, while out on a test.
>
> Buying this car, is expensive indeed;
>
> But I want it, desire it, this car I need.

**What car am I wanting to buy?**

You’ll need the make and model to be correct.

Also, how many clues did you find?

**Hint**:

> A hint you may need, this car is fun; look no further than a union of ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want-

> Aston martin. probably the DB11 (you said union of ones)

Reason

> British made, driven by 007 aka james bond, it is a famous and expensive sports car brand

Comment: You’re halfway there; I’m looking at a specific model.

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: ah, haha too late eh

Answer (score 3):

Building on Shahriar's answer:

Is it:

> Aston Martin One-77?

British designed, like driving in heaven;
A famous car worldwide, driven by seven.

> British made, driven by 007, and only 77 of them were made

Look no further than a union of ones.

> Bit of a stretch, it's a ONE-77. Hopefully can be interpreted as union With ones?

Comment: If only! That car falls into a category I just can’t afford! Great answer!